# upup: Can I supply more than one page per domain?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm using [upup](https://www.talater.com/upup/) to make offline content available. I'd like to supply several pages for a single domain:

- page1.php contains an upup.js code snippet to make page1_off.php available when offline.
- page2.php contains an upup.js code snippet to make page2_off.php available when offline.
- etc.

This is working, but I get an error when trying to navigate between pages. This is what happens:

- When I'm on page1 without internet connection, then navigate to page2, I still see the contents of page1.
- When I'm on page2 without internet connection, then navigate to page1, I still see the contents of page2.

When I'm on example.com, then go offline, then try to open any of the pages, there's no problem.

*How can I make this work?*

Sample JavaScript:

```
UpUp.start({
  "content-url": "/offlinedata/page1_off.php",
});
```

*Also, should it be possible to list pages as assets?* For me, this is not working:

```
<script>
    UpUp.start({
      'content-url': 'offline.html',
      'assets': ['page1_off.php', 'page2_off.php']
    });
  </script>
```

Thanks
Pida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that upup doesn't support more than one page per domain yet. There's an issue on [Github](https://github.com/TalAter/UpUp/issues/9) named "Allow storing different content for different areas of the site".